# using imdbapi.com to popluate textboxes with jquery/ajax

Tags: ajax, api, jquery, imdb

I'm trying to get the movie details from IMDB according to the title of a movie, i am using imdbapi.com's API to do this.

Now it seems to be returning the JSON just fine, however i can't seem to populate the textbox and can not for the life of me work out why its not populating.

Can someone please check this out and see if you can shed some light?

I have tried :

```
function getData(title) {
    $.getJSON('http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=' + title,
      function (data) {
          $('#TextBox2').text(data.Plot);
      }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('#TextBox2').val(data.Plot);